# Whats a good method for hanging heavy curtains in a timbre frame wall?

Tags: drywall, drill, curtain-rail

I've moved into a timber frame house. I have read a bit about plasterboard and using the right plugs and fixings but am still unsure. The curtains are blackout so have a bit of weight to them. The curtain mounts are as shown in the image. One hole to hang on a screw and another hole to secure the mount with a second screw.
[image: Curtain bracket]

The place I want to put the mount is not over a stud (even though my stud finder said it was) so I need fixings. I plan to use self-drill fixings like below for the top hole.
https://www.fischer.co.uk/en-gb/products/cavity-fixings/board-fixing/plasterboard-fixing-metal-gkm

And these for the lower hole
https://www.screwfix.com/p/fischer-plasterboard-plugs-hdf-10-x-28mm-100-pack/58219

The reason I'm using different ones is that the holes are fairly close together and I don't want risk them touching and weakening the wall.

Is this a good method?

Finally, I've tried it on one and had to stop as I couldn't drill in the lower screw, the bracket gets in the way. Is there a good method/tool to screw in parts when a drill/screwdriver can't line up straight?
[image: Drill won't fit]

Comment: Is there a chance you just missed the stud by a quarter of an inch? If so, I'd just move it to the side, and patch the first holes. I've never had any luck with the sheetrock anchor things, they always pull out. And if you have any pets/children that will yank on those curtains it'll happen sooner rather than later.

Comment: For hard to reach places there are different types of screwdrivers.  Stubby, offsets,  with your picture might do with putting screw in at a slight angle with a driver with a long shaft to miss the hook.  Would move hook to hit a stud, anchors will usually fail for stuff like curtains.

Answer (score 2):

**Mount a board across the studs then mount curtain supports to the board.**

[image: board]

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/262686590739630194/

This would clearly work.  There has got to be studs in there somewhere and your board can transfer the load to them rather than some sort of precarious mollybolt that is going to pull out of the wall when the curtains get a tug.

I am a little surprised that someone would post this image with their logo on it.  I like the structural aspects but the plain wood colored board does not look that great.  You could get a board with some molding, or paint it to match the window trim or otherwise do it in a way that makes it less of a kludge.

---

Re drilling thru a bracket: hold bracket where desired, mark thru holes with pencil.  Mark top edge with pencil.  Remove bracket.  Do the same with other brackets.  Make sure that all top edges are on the same horizontal line!  Drill holes at pencil marks.  This also avoids you marring bracket or dulling drill bit by drilling thru piece of metal.

If you are going to use the suggested board method you can put the brackets on the board on your workbench before you put the board on the wall.

Re drill does not fit under bracket: time to bust out that short little screwdriver, or your socket set.

Answer (score 1):

If these curtains will always stay open and are purely decorative, your approach is good.  I would use two of your first anchors on each bracket, you don't need different anchors and the first one is better.

If you've never done this before, find a construction site, take a piece of scrap drywall from the dumpster, and practice to find what size drill, what size screw, and how tightly to drive in the anchor and screw to get the maximum strength.   A little practice will go a long way.

On the other hand, if the curtains will be opened and closed regularly, if they will be handled by people, I would find a way to use studs.  Make more effort to find them.  Buy a different stud finder.  Get a longer rod.  Or mount a board as suggested in the other answer.

To drive in the second screw you can use a driver extension for your drill, or just a long screwdriver.
[image: driver extension]
[image: long screwdriver]

Or if even that doesn't work you can use a right angle adapter for your drill or a right angle screwdriver.
[image: right angle drill adapter]
[image: right angle screwdriver]